# OpenFDA API - how to query on drug name with more than one word

Tags: openfda, api

Try running this query: https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?&search=brand_name:tylenol+number+three
I've also tried the %20 instead of '+' and it didn't work either.
I'm trying to pull up the information for brand name drug Tylenol #3.
It returns the drug Silicea (silicon dioxide).
I'd have to assume then that my syntax is incorrect, but I can't seem to find what the correct syntax is.
Does anyone else have experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query appears to work for a two-word query of `"infants tylenol"`

```
 https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=brand_name:%22infants%20tylenol%22
```

%22 is for a double quote and %20 is a space

I wonder if there is a brand name drug named `tylenol #3` based on my searches though, considering the following query doesn't return any matches for that

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=brand_name:%22tylenol%22&count=openfda.brand_name.exact
```

Comment: Yes, there is a brand name drug named Tylenol #3.  I also tried Adderall XR and the API returns Tegretol XR.  I'm a pharmacist and trying to get this integrated into my software, but I'm finding a lot of inaccuracies like this.

Comment: Not seeing it on DailyMed under that name either: https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/search.cfm?labeltype=all&query=tylenol+3

Comment: Do you know the NDC # or perhaps its imprints/shape/color?

Comment: https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Overview&DrugName=TYLENOL%20W%2F%20CODEINE%20NO%2E%203

Comment: It looks like the brand name product was re-labeled as "Tylenol with Codeine #3".  When I tried: https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?&search=brand_name:tylenol%20with%20codeine it still didn't work.  The only way I could get it to come up was as: https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?&search=brand_name:%22tylenol%20with%20codeine%22  I didn't realize that not containing the quotes around the drug name would be that significant.  Thanks for your help again!